# Building a constructer that holds dates

Tags: c++

I was trying to build a constructer that holds variables, and call the constructor in the main function so I can execute the dates by using this constructor, as you see

```
class Date
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
public:
    Date(int d, int m, int y) {
        d = day;
        m = month;
        y = year;
    }
public:
    void print()
    {
        cout << "The Day is : " << day << endl;
        cout << "The Month is : " << month << endl;
        cout << "The Year is : " << year << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Date birth(4, 4, 2004);
    birth.print();
}
```

The issue is that I'm getting a different value than the output I think it should be:

```
The Day is : 4
The Month is : 4 
The Year is : 2004
```

But I'm getting this instead:

```
The Day is : -858993460    
The Month is : -858993460    
The Year is : -858993460
```

I think this is the memory address or something like that, but why am I'm getting it rather than the value that I want?

Comment: You have your assignments backwards. Try `day = d` instead of `d = day`.

Answer (score 4):

You're doing the assignment in the wrong direction.
The way to visualize this is:

```
target = source;
```

So the correct way to write the constructor is:

```
Date(int d, int m, int y) {
    day = d;
    month = m;
    year = y;
}
```